# Celluloid Pool has dead actors first time called

Tags: ruby, celluloid

Everytime I launch the app, the first time I call it, it returns Dead Actors.  After that it returns as expected.

```
require 'celluloid'

class BatchProcess
  include Celluloid
  POOL = BatchProcess.pool(size: 6)

  attr_accessor :base_url, :futures, :objects, :pool, :array

  def initialize(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    @base_url = options[:base_url] || "http://some_site.com"
    @futures = []
    @objects = {}
  end

  def fetch(array)
    @pool = POOL
    @array = array
    start
  end

  def start
    @grouped_sites = @array.group_by{|i| i[:main_site]}
    @grouped_sites.each do |main_site, queries|
      batched_url(main_site, queries)
    end
    futures.each {|f| @objects.merge!(f.value) if f.value}
  end

  def batched_urls(main_site, queries)
    queries.each do |query|
      futures << pool.future(:get_url, main_site, query)
    end
  end

  def get_url(main_site, query)
    # get http url and parse information process into json data
  end 
end
```

I then call it from my controller `BatchProcess.new.fetch(array_of_sites_to_parse)`

I did try to put the `@pool = BatchProcess.pool` in my initializer, it did not error, but actors grew exponentially with every request.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're instantiating the Pool as a `class` constant before `initialize` is defined. At the point your `POOL` constant is set, `initialize` does not exist yet, so none of your instance variables are initialized.

Upon the second try, the `initialize` will be defined.